# How to update Visual Studio Template Cache

Tags: visual-studio-2008

I've updated a default template in Visual Studio 2008 with the following path:

> C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\ItemTemplates\Web\CSharp\1033

But when I've tried adding a new file with this type of template, I'm still getting the old version which I have found to be cached in this folder path:

> C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\ItemTemplatesCache\Web\CSharp\1033

What I would like to know is when does a new project template get pulled from it's zip file and put into the Item Tempate Cache in visual studio?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Open up the Visual Studio Command Prompt and type in:

```
devenv /installvstemplates
```

Source: [How to Edit Visual Studio Templates](http://www.thecodinghumanist.com/Content/HowToEditVSTemplates.aspx)

Comment: Will Visual Studio do this automatically at sometime or is this always something that needs to be done manually.

Comment: I also had to run this statement:
devenv /resetsettings

Comment: Note that you must run this with elevated privileges.

Comment: /resetsettings was not necessary for me. Just the elevation. Also note that it can take a while to run, so open taskman and make sure that devenv is done and exited before trying to use the new templates.

Answer (score 11):

Launch "Developer Command Prompt for VS 2022" as Administrator

```
devenv /updateconfiguration
```

See: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/cannot-remove-item-template/27424

/installvstemplates did not work me in VS 2022.

Comment: ~~Somehow this did nothing to me but created an empty folder `%USERPROFILE%\Documents\Visual Studio 2022`. I had empty templates upon fresh install of 17.5.0 :( I had to copy templates manually as in https://stackoverflow.com/a/46895353/673826 ~~ Now I'm confused as I see new project templates with just empty folder in my documents.

Comment: It's incredibly confusing. When you use the "Export Template" function in Visual Studio, it by default goes into `%USERPROFILE%\Documents\Visual Studio 2022\My Exported Templates`.  If you check the box that says "Import Into Visual Studio" it puts a copy somewhere in `%USERPROFILE%\Documents\Visual Studio 2022\Templates`. But it maintains a cache of all those templates in yet another place, which is why we have to run this `devenv /updateconfiguration` command, to update it if you make a manual change to a template.  That's my understanding at this point, anyway.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue.
What was here did not work for me.
What I did however is to go to a specific folder and edit the files directly.
Just go there :

```
%AppData%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\{some_version}\ItemTemplatesCache\
```

It contains folders named after the zip files from your archives in the template folder.
I needed admin priviledge for edits.

Enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar issue, and what worked for me was the following:

Once I placed the new or updated zip files in the ProjectTemplates folder, I reexported the template of a project. During this process, I made sure to check the **"Automatically import the template into Visual Studio"** option. After doing this, my VS2022 detected and included all the new and updated templates from the ProjectTemplates folder.