# Visual Studio 2012 project template custom params & renaming issues

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-templates

**Task:**
I want to create a project template from a Visual Studio 2012 project, so I can quickly create similar projects. This requires files to be renamed and the root namespace to be changed. Unfortunately, this does not happen...

**What has been done:**

1. I've created the project and replaced certain names as specified by the MSDN pages. One replacement is the `$safeprojectname$`, the other is a custom parameter: `$custom1$`.
2. The project has been exported as a project template via the *File --> Export Template...* option.
3. I've unzipped the created zip file.
4. I've edited the *.vstemplate* and *.csproject* files. The code is found below.
5. I've rezipped the files.
6. Visual Studio has been restarted, and a project has been opened.
7. I go for *Add --> New Project --> *my custom template**, give it a name and add the project.
8. The project gets added and `$safeprojectname$` gets replaced. The files are **not** renamed and `$custom1` does **not** get replaced.

**MyTemplate.vstemplate**

```
<VSTemplate Version="3.0.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/vstemplate/2005" Type="Project">
   <TemplateData>
      <Name>MyTemplateName</Name>
      <Description>My Description</Description>
      <ProjectType>CSharp</ProjectType>
      <ProjectSubType></ProjectSubType>
      <SortOrder>1000</SortOrder>
      <CreateNewFolder>true</CreateNewFolder>
      <DefaultName>My Default Name</DefaultName>
      <ProvideDefaultName>true</ProvideDefaultName>
      <LocationField>Enabled</LocationField>
      <EnableLocationBrowseButton>true</EnableLocationBrowseButton>
      <Icon>__TemplateIcon.ico</Icon>
   </TemplateData>
   <TemplateContent>
      <Project TargetFileName="MyTemplate.csproj" File="MyTemplate.csproj" ReplaceParameters="true">
         <ProjectItem ReplaceParameters="true" TargetFileName="app.config">app.config</ProjectItem>
         <ProjectItem ReplaceParameters="true" TargetFileName="$safeprojectname$Data.cs">Data.cs</ProjectItem>
         <ProjectItem ReplaceParameters="true" TargetFileName="$safeprojectname$.cs">Main.cs</ProjectItem>
         <ProjectItem ReplaceParameters="true" TargetFileName="$safeprojectname$Form.xaml">Form.xaml</ProjectItem>
         <ProjectItem ReplaceParameters="true" TargetFileName="$safeprojectname$Form.xaml.cs">Form.xaml.cs</ProjectItem>
         <Folder Name="Properties" TargetFolderName="Properties">
            <ProjectItem ReplaceParameters="true" TargetFileName="AssemblyInfo.cs">AssemblyInfo.cs</ProjectItem>
            <ProjectItem ReplaceParameters="true" TargetFileName="Settings.settings">Settings.settings</ProjectItem>
            <ProjectItem ReplaceParameters="true" TargetFileName="Settings.Designer.cs">Settings.Designer.cs</ProjectItem>
         </Folder>
      </Project>
      <CustomParameters>
         <CustomParameter Name="$custom1$" Value="Some.Custom.Namespace.Prefix."/>
      <CustomParameters>
   </TemplateContent>
</VSTemplate>
```

**MyTemplate.csproj**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
    <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props')" />
    <PropertyGroup>
        ...
    <OutputType>Library</OutputType>
    <RootNamespace>$custom1$$safeprojectname$</RootNamespace>
    <AssemblyName>$safeprojectname$</AssemblyName>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
        <Compile Include="$safeprojectname$.cs" />
        <Compile Include="$safeprojectname$Data.cs" />
        <Compile Include="$safeprojectname$Form.xaml.cs">
            <DependentUpon>$safeprojectname$Form.xaml</DependentUpon>
        </Compile>
        <Compile Include="Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs" />
        <Compile Include="Properties\Settings.Designer.cs">
            <AutoGen>True</AutoGen>
            <DesignTimeSharedInput>True</DesignTimeSharedInput>
            <DependentUpon>Settings.settings</DependentUpon>
        </Compile>
    </ItemGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
        <Page Include="$safeprojectname$Form.xaml">
            <SubType>Designer</SubType>
            <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
        </Page>
    </ItemGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
        <None Include="app.config" />
        <None Include="Properties\Settings.settings">
            <Generator>PublicSettingsSingleFileGenerator</Generator>
            <LastGenOutput>Settings.Designer.cs</LastGenOutput>
        </None>
    </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

**Question?**
How do I get Visual Studio to change the $custom1$ parameter in the files and to rename the files, like Main.cs, to $safeprojectname$.cs?

**What doesn't work**

- Following the steps on the MSDN pages got me nowhere; neither the filenames change, nor the custom parameter.
- Searching Google gave me MSDN pages, or references to them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how visual stuido handels exported templates, but i know from modifing the default templates that  visual studio has two versions of a template. One you will find in the "ProjectTemplate" folder the other will be in "ProjectTemplateCache".

Maybe your exported template is still inside the cach without your modifications.
Try to refresh the cache by statring visual studio from cmd using the parameter: "devenv /installvstemplates" or "devenv /setup".

If you want to create more than one template, I recommend to download the Visual Studio and use a VSIX project to depoly the templates. The SDK also allow to debug the templates in a much more efficent way. You can press Debug and you will recive a Visual Studio instance with a installation of your VSIX (your templates).

Comment: D'oh... It appears I have either read past some information on the MSDN, or the MSDN is not specific enough. The folder that gets opened, when exporting a template, is not the template being loaded. In stead, you need to go to the ..\Templates\ folder. I'll mark this answer as the answer, as it pointed my in the right direction. Thanks.

Comment: Knots, your post helped me figure out how to rename the file names in my project.  Do you know how to replace the actual names of the projects???

Comment: What Name do you mean? The display name of an project or the default name if you create an project?

Comment: The name of the project that gets created by the template Sukram.

Comment: IF I take your MyTemplate.vstemplate example above I have tried to change the name of my project based on a user defined value like so: <Project TargetFileName="$customvalue".csproj" File="MyTemplate.csproj" ReplaceParameters="true"> but it doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

Your steps and project files look correct. You need to update the Visual Studio Template Cache. The answer in [How to update Visual Studio Template Cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1717355/how-to-update-visual-studio-template-cache) links to the steps.

Here are the steps that worked for me (note your user name will be different):

1. Close all open Visual Studio instances.
2. Edit the copy of your template located in `C:\Users\chadd\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\My Exported Templates` - follow steps in above in OP.
3. Search to find other copies of your Template and delete them. I have Visual Studio 2013 and found copies in these two directories.  `C:\Users\chadd\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0\ProjectTemplatesCache` `C:\Users\chadd\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Templates\ProjectTemplates`
4. Copy the edited version of yourTemplate.zip into `C:\Users\chadd\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Templates\ProjectTemplates`
5. Open a command prompt for Visual Studio (Run as Administrator) and enter `devenv /installvstemplates` This step takes a while (several minutes) so be patient for the command prompt to return.
6. Open Visual Studio verify your modified template is now working.