# Cannot find LightSpeed on Visual Studio items

Tags: visual-studio-2015, orm, lightspeed

I have just installed **LightSpeed** and it does not appear in Visual C# items list. Do I have to activate it from somewhere?

I am using:

- Windows 8.1
- Visual Studio 2015

I have already tried to refresh the template caches of Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installing nightly build of LightSpeed and [refreshing again the template caches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1717355/how-to-update-visual-studio-template-cache) solved my problem.